# How to add hyphen in values in SAS Enterprise Guide (to put in date format)?

Tags: sas

I have a table in SAS that has a column of dates but are not in the typical date format (DD-MM-YY). For example, one of them is

> 21JUN2012:00:00:00

What can I do so that it is in the format

> 21-Jun-12

? I am using SAS Enterprise Guide so I know I would have to selected Computed Column but I do not know how to go from there. I was thinking of using TRANWRD but I can't seem to get it work.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click on the column to be converted and select Properties.
- Change the type to Numeric and click Yes in the warning prompt regarding precision.
- Change the Group to Date.
- Click Informats; the selected value under Categories should be Date.
- Change the informat to DDMMYYSw.
- Under Attributes, assign an overall width of 10
- Click Formats; the selected value under Categories should be Date.
- Change the format to DDMMYYSw.
- Under Attributes, assign an overall width of 10.
- Click OK
- If the conversion results are correct in the Preview Results window,
  click Commit changes.

[Reference](https://communities.sas.com/thread/52752)

Comment: Thanks, but I put this in the code log but it didn't work.. am I doing something wrong? Also is there is a way to do it without coding? I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide

Comment: if you want to write to the table in dddmmyy time then you should use EURDFDT read this link i think it will be helpful https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm

Comment: I can't click informats, the drop down lists are greyed out. Same with Numeric

Comment: You will have to change the permissions on the table to make it editable

Answer (score 0):

There are many date formats and informats available in SAS to change the date format being presented.  A full list of the formats can be found [here in the SAS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p1wj0wt2ebe2a0n1lv4lem9hdc0v.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n19nv9ogyfvl89n1jg665kaz343c).  The format you want is `ddmmyyd.` and you can just apply the format to the date value (see col1_ example).

For datetime values, you need to use the `DATEPART` function to extract the date value before applying the format (see col2_ and col3_ examples below).

If your date is provided as text, you need to apply an informat to it to convert it to SAS date value and then you can apply your desired date format to the value using `PUT` statements.  Including converting this value back to text (see col4_ examples below).

```
data date_infile;
    infile datalines delimiter=',';
    input col1_date :date9. col2_dtime :datetime18. col3_dtime :datetime18. col4_text $18.;
    format col1_date date9. col2_dtime col3_dtime datetime18.;
    datalines;
21jun2012,21JUN2012:00:00:00,21JUN2012:12:34:56,21JUN2012:00:00:00
11aug2012,11AUG2012:00:00:00,11AUG2012:01:23:45,11AUG2012:00:00:00
05oct2019,05OCT2019:00:00:00,05OCT2019:01:23:45,05OCT2019:00:00:00
;
run;

data date_results;
    set date_infile;
    format col1_date col2_date col3_date col4_date ddmmyyd.;
    col2_date = datepart(col2_dtime);
    col3_date = datepart(col3_dtime);
    col4_date = datepart(input(col4_text, datetime18.));
    col4_date_as_text = put(put(datepart(input(col4_text, datetime18.)), ddmmyyd.), $8.);
run;
```